# iOS 6 Navigation Bar Color in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, storyboard, ios7

I'd spent a few months developing an application for iOS 6 when I updated to Xcode 5. I updated the application to fit with the iOS 7 style, when I decided to run the application again on iOS 6.1. I found that my previously black navigation bar had turned white.

I swapped my storyboard to be viewed as "iOS 6.1 and Earlier", and found that the color of the navigation bar was white, even though it was set to "Opaque Black Navigation Bar" in the simulated metrics.

Any ideas on how to fix this? I've already tried manually setting the child view top bars to "Opaque Black Navigation Bar" as well. This changes the color of the navigation bar for the child to appear black on the storyboard, but has no effect on the application when run on the simulator.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like what I needed to do was check if the device was running a version less than iOS 7, then set

```
[[[self navigationController] navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Answer (score 13):

For setting the color of the navigation bar, I did the following:

```
if([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(barTintColor)])
{
    // iOS7
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:236.0/255.0 green:139.0/255.0 blue:23.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}
else
{
    // older
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:236.0/255.0 green:139.0/255.0 blue:23.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}
```

Hopefully somebody will find it helpful...

Comment: This actually throws an error message when compiled and run on an iOS 6 device. A better way to determine iOS version is this: '
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
   // Load resources for iOS 6.1 or earlier
} else {
   // Load resources for iOS 7 or later
}
' see here: 
[link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/SupportingEarlieriOS.html)

Comment: The code works on iOS6, iOS6.1, iOS7 without any problems. The idea is to check if the navigationBar "respondsToSelector"... And this is the way to implement it. Of course, there are a lot of other ways to check the version... Thank you for the link

Answer (score 0):

`UIBarStyleBlackOpaque` is deprecated.

Use `UIBarStyleBlack` instead.

Alternatively in iOS 7 you can set the `barTintColor` property to black.

Answer (score 0):

for :- iOS 7

```
// set tint color in io s6
[[[self navigationController] navigationBar] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

for :- iOS 7

```
// set translucent property to NO in iOS 7 
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent=NO;
// set Bar tint color 
[[[self navigationController] navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
// But I would recommend Use Images instead of color.
```

for iOS 6 :- 320 X 44 size of Image
for iOS 7 :- 320 X 64 size of Image

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  It really helped... Thank you!